# Can't connect to database with db client [08001]

Tags: mysql, database, laravel, homestead

I am using `laravel homestead` on linux and when I want to connect to database with `phpstorm` or `DBeaver` I receive:

```
[08001] Could not create connection to database server. Attempted reconnect 3 times. Giving up.
Index 5 out of bounds for length 5.
```

I investigate and find that problem could be with jdbc driver but all of my drivers are up to date. On homestead I use mysql 5.7 and both (phpstrom and DBeaver) are up to date.

Answer (score 1):

I finally figure out. For homestead on linux you need to pass this credentials:

```
host: 192.168.10.10
```

instead of `127.0.0.1` or `localhost`

username and password are the same: `homestead` and `secret`